Pydantic model is not callable
I create a custom model, based on pydantic BaseModel like this:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CustomModel(BaseModel):

    field1: int
    field2: str

and when i define an instance like this
def validate_data(validator: CustomModel, custom_dict: dict) -> None:
    cm = validator(**custom_dict)

both pyright and mypy report an error '"CustomModel" not callable  [operator]'
if i try to write the model directly - there is no error.
def validate_data(validator: CustomModel, custom_dict: dict) -> None:
    cm = CustomModel(**custom_dict)

the function call looks like this:
x = validate_date(validator=CustomModel, custom_dict=custom_dict)


Possible duplicate: Type hints with user defined classes. You want type[CustomModel] instead of just CustomModel.

This part of the code is wrong:
def validate_data(validator: CustomModel, custom_dict: dict) -> None:
    cm = validator(**custom_dict)

The parameter validator is an instance of the CustomModel class. I do not know your full implementation, but I assume that validator(**custom_dict) makes no sense in the same way this makes no sense:
my_str = "Hello"
my_str(**custom_dict)

or the following (also wrong) example:
class MyClass:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = MyClass()
    p()

That of course does not work for the same reason your code isn't working.
You didn't show how you're calling the validate_data method, but the problem may be there. You should add additional context for further analysis.

i pass classes without calling init, so yes, i had to use Type[CustomModel]

Can you add 1) How you are importing the class 2) How you are calling the validate_data method? :)
